# steroid and ionic css compatibility?

Tags: android, css, cordova, ionic-framework, steroids

by default steroids uses ionic for it's css framework.

Testing today it looks like i get very different results on 2 different android devices

[Galaxy s2 – i9100 running android 4.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTOcc.jpg)

[Galaxy Tab – P7500 running android .2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5d6a.jpg)

My questions are:

- is this expected?
- if no, is there any idea what i might be doing wrong? are there different config files between android tablet/phone?
- if yes, is there another css framework people know of that might give me more consistent results across devices?!

Answer (score 0):

bah. the issue is described here:
http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/known_issues/android-4-4/

specifically that

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

breaks css and shows loading.png